# Customize FROM name and email on PHP email?

Tags: php, wordpress

how do I set a custom NAME and EMAIL address to send FROM?

```
function send_customer_purchase_notification_ready( $payment_id, $new_status ) {
    $message->IsHTML(true);

    $order_status = rpress_get_option( $new_status );
    $check_notification_enabled = isset( $order_status['enable_notification'] ) ? true : false;

    if ( !empty( $payment_id ) && $check_notification_enabled && $new_status !== 'pending' && $new_status == 'ready' ) {                  
        $message = 'The order <strong>#' .$payment_id. '</strong> is ready for delivery!';
        $to = 'isleek@gmail.com';
        $subject = "READY FOR PICKUP";
        $headers = ''; 
        //Here put your Validation and send mail
        $sent = wp_mail($to, $subject, strip_tags($message), $headers);
    }
}
add_action( 'rpress_update_order_status', 'send_customer_purchase_notification_ready' , 10, 2 );
```

ALSO, this is not related to the title but if you can help me.. would be awesome: the email doesn't show the order # as bold (`$payment_id`)... even though I set the `$message->IsHTML(true);`

Comment: add `$headers .= "From: CustomName <custom@email.com>\r\n"`

Comment: You need to configure your worpdress `phpmailer` to set custom from name and email for this custom email. Headers will not override the from email. It the from email is set to something static in the settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress has tons of filters that let you easily change stuff as you need.

in that case, i believe you can use the filter `wp_mail_content_type`, `wp_mail_from`, and `wp_mail_from_name`. jsut create function callback for each filter and add filter for it

example:

```
function change_content_type( $content_type ) {
    return 'text/html';
}

function change_from_email( $from_email ) {
    return 'you@company.com';
}

function change_from_name( $from_name ) {
    return 'Your Name';
}
```

and then you can add filter for it

```
add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'change_content_type' );
add_filter( 'wp_mail_from', 'change_from_email' );
add_filter( 'wp_mail_from_name', 'change_from_name' );
```

or just to be safe, you can only use the filters to only affect your `send_customer_purchase_notification_ready` email, by adding the filters right before you call the `wp_mail()` and safely remove it afterward

```
// Add filters
add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'change_content_type' );
add_filter( 'wp_mail_from', 'change_from_email' );
add_filter( 'wp_mail_from_name', 'change_from_name' );

// Send your email
$sent = wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

// remove the filters
remove_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'change_content_type' );
remove_filter( 'wp_mail_from', 'change_from_email' );
remove_filter( 'wp_mail_from_name', 'change_from_name' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `FROM` in the headers (remove the Reply-To if not needed)

```
$headers = 'From: ' . $yourEmail . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $yourEmail . "\r\n";
```

> the email doesn't show the order # as bold

... because of the `strip_tags` function, which removes HTML elements in the message.

Do:

```
//
$sent = wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

You might also want/need to look at:

- [`wp_mail_content_type`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_mail_content_type/)
- [`wp_mail`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/)